# how to use stylesheets in my rails 3.2 app to use it then in Heroku? Error: ActionView::Template::Error (file.css isn't precompiled)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, stylesheet

in my rails 3.2 app have the following layouts, using [ruby guides:assets pipelin](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

```
application layout:
...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>
...

participant layout:
...
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
...
```

and in app/assets/stylesheets I have manifest(application.css) and participant.css.scss

I've insered, learning by [heroku assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets), in config/application.rb :

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

and I've done 'rake assets:precompile' in my local app,that created public/assets with various files.

In local everything works fine !!

Then, learning by [Asset Pipeline on Heroku Cedar](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar), I made a commit to the repository and I did push on Heroku, and the console said:

```
...
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally
...
```

But when I go to call myApp / participants it gives the following error:

```
2012-12-05T13:40:08+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/participants" for 2.235.56.84 at     2012-12-05 13:40:08 +0000
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ParticipantsController#index as HTML
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered participants/index.html.erb within layouts/participants (4.8ms)
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (participants.css isn't precompiled):
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     5: <head>
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <title>Participants: <%= controller.action_name %></title>
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     9: </head>
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 154ms
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     10: <body>
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:     11: 
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/layouts/participants.html.erb:8:in `_app_views_layouts_participants_html_erb__1645329556414684428_17128800'
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/participants_controller.rb:29:in `index'
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]:
2012-12-05T13:40:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-05T13:40:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-12-05T13:40:13+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
2012-12-05T13:40:15+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

while when I call myApp/?token=test and then loads layout/application everything works fine:

```
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/?token=test" for 2.235.56.84 at     2012-12-05 13:46:06 +0000
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MainController#index as HTML
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"token"=>"test"}
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 3.7ms | ActiveRecord: 16.0ms)
 2012-12-05T13:46:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered main/noYaml.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
```

what is missing or what I did wrong?

Comment: have you pushed the compiled assets to heroku?

Comment: Yes, as you can see above, I followed the instructions doing git add, git commit and git push, that ran "-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline Detected manifest.yml, assuming assets were compiled locally"